# Insert a record in two table with dependency in ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can you guys give a sample query for inserting records in two table. Here's my scenario...

```
   insert into table1 (name) values ('jay') -- ID is auto increment
   insert into table2 (id,name2) values (1,'jay2') -- value 1 is the ID from first query
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE(id INT)

INSERT INTO table1(name)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @ids
VALUES('jay')

INSERT INTO table2(id, name2)
    SELECT id, 'jay2'
    FROM @ids
```

---

Another is to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`:

```
INSERT INTO table1(name) VALUES('jay')

INSERT INTO table2(id, name2)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'jay2'
```

Comment: I was writing both these solution... +1 for being faster than me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in SQL

Comment: You should expand your answer to describe _how_ those two functions are used. As it is your answer will prompt more questions.